# How to do_action and get a return value?

Tags: actions

So there is the following scenario.

I add an action to clean logs from the database:

```
add_action( 'myplugin_clean_logs', array( 'MyPlugin_Logs', 'clean_logs' ) );
```

Now I want to run this action periodically:

```
wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'daily', 'myplugin_clean_logs' );
```

and execute it manually:

```
do_action( 'myplugin_clean_logs' );
```

The method `MyPlugin_Logs::clean_logs` returns the count of affected rows or false if something went the other direction.

Now I want to display the number of rows that have been deleted. I would imagine something like this:

```
$affected_rows = do_action( 'myplugin_clean_logs' );
echo $affected_rows . ' entries have been deleted.';
```

But as `do_action` will not return any value, I have no idea how to get the return value.

Should I execute the method directly on a manual run, but use the action on schedule events?

Comment: You don't want to be echo'ing anything on a scheduled event, so yes, I would execute the method directly on a manual run (I'm assuming the administrator would trigger this, and you want to show them the output).

Answer (score 16):

The cool thing is a filter is the same as an action, only it returns a value, so just set it up as a filter instead:

`add_filter( 'myplugin_clean_logs', array( 'MyPlugin_Logs', 'clean_logs' ) );`

Then something like:

```
$affected_rows = '';
$affected_rows = apply_filters( 'myplugin_clean_logs', $affected_rows );
```

should pass `$affected_rows` to `clean_logs()` (and whatever other functions you may have hooked to `myplugin_clean_logs`) and assign the return value back to `$affected_rows`.

Comment: downvoted as this is hacking code instead of developing software. If actions were just a subset of filters there would not have been any need of them. Cron can not pass value therefor it should not be hooked as a filter even if the buggy core code allows you to do such shemigans :)

Comment: Point taken. I get that the *intent* of the two different things, but to look at the core code here, the whole `do_action()` thing is nothing more than an elaborate hack of `apply_filters()` :)

Comment: not the only bad design in core which in part is what leads to confusion that lead to questions like this

Comment: We need to work with what we've got, so while I understand Mark's point of view I still think this is a legit answer - *unless* of course core changes this approach in future, but I think that unlikely due to the massive backwards compatibility problems it would introduce.

Comment: Thanks, @TimMalone. I do appreciate @mark-kaplun 's  objection. My answer describes how to work around `do_action()` not returning a value rather than how to design a solution in congruence with `do_action()`s intent. If someone is able to do what he's asking, that answer deserves to be the accepted answer. My first thought would be to have the hooked method (assuming the OP is using an OOP design for this plugin) drop it's result into a protected property of the plugin class and then write a quick getter to pull it out at some later point. But that's just a wild hair of an idea!

Comment: @Casper the wordpress docs explicitly distinguish between actions and filters. As far as I understood it, a filter is there for actual filtering things and is as such more a tool than an executer. Maybe this is just theory and more a code design difference than a real world case. At first I had a similar idea of passing a variable by reference (though didnt test it, if it works), I avoided it to not mess up the code.

Comment: @TimMalone, sometimes when you have a confusing coding problem you should stop and ask yourself if it is a coding problem or a design problem

Comment: @Aley, sorry actually wrote a comment to the question but apperantly forgot to send, but you can get the drift of what I think (you need to handle it differently in both cases) from the comments here

Comment: Why not just use a PHP Function call instead, and that way no need for do_action or apply_filters.  Place the function inside functions.php file.

Comment: FWIW this is how WooCommerce does it in their templates. Theory or best practices aside this is essentially an accepted way of doing things as WooCommerce is now officially a part of Wordpress/Automattic.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question but to answer the original question "How to do_action and get a return value?" for anyone looking you can do this using output buffering.

```
ob_start();
    do_action( 'myplugin_clean_logs' );
$action_data = ob_get_clean();
```

This way you can store the do_action content in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Never used this function and haven't tested this, but might it work?  [do_action_ref_array()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action_ref_array/).

```
function myplugin_clean_logs_fn() {
    $args = array(
        'param1'        => 'val1',
        'param2'        => 'val2',
        'affected_rows' => 0,
    );
    do_action_ref_array( 'myplugin_clean_logs', &$args );
    return $args['affected_rows'];
}

// CALL IT
$affected_rows = my_plugin_clean_logs();
echo $affected_rows .' entr'. ($args['affected_rows']*1===1?'y':'ies') .' deleted.';

// SCHEDULE IT
add_action('myplugin_clean_logs_call_fn', 'myplugin_clean_logs_fn');
wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'daily', 'myplugin_clean_logs_call_fn' );

// A SAMPLE FILTER
add_action('myplugin_clean_logs', function($args) {
    // Cleaning process
    // For each log affected, increment $args['affected_rows'] accordingly
}, 10, 3);
```

If that doesn't work, why not just filter the thing like Caspar suggested?  I mean, that is the purpose of a filter, and in this case the number of affected rows is the thing being filtered.  (I miss the old MortCore.  Anyone remember how it handled return values, pass-by-reference, and arguments with just a single three parameter function?)

Comment: This is a horrible answer, as passing in and modifying values by reference is really bad practice. Honestly, this answer really doesn't provide value in the context of the question and should likely be removed or changed to a comment.
Additionally, using anonymous functions with hooks is also bad practice, as it makes them impossible to unhook.

Comment: I agree for the same above mentioned reasons, that this is not a recommended path. If you for some reason need to get a return value from an action, and need something quick and dirty, I would prefer Caspars solution. If you are developing something with a life-cycle ahead of it, I would look for a more robust way. Coming to think of, how about admin notices? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_notices/